# I'm not getting any error but why I cannot insert data into database table?

Tags: java, derby

I try to insert data into database table but it just can't and there is no error detected there. If someone can help me finding where is my mistake. I'm glad to know that

This is my servlet

```
Connection theConnection = null;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String nameL = request.getParameter("name");
String questionL = request.getParameter("question");
String schemeL = request.getParameter("scheme");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet InputData</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet InputData at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.println("<P align=center>");
        out.println("<form name=form1 action=\"http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/-\">");
        out.println("<p>");
        out.println("<input type=submit name=\"submit\" value=\"GET DATA FROM DB\">");
        out.println("</p>");
        out.println("</form>");

        // Load database driver
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
                System.out.println(cnfe);
    }
        // Create a Connection to contacts db Data source
        try {
            theConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURI,"demo","demo");
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.out.println(sqle);
    }
        // prepare statement for inserting data into table
        try {

            str = "INSERT INTO DEMO.QUESTION "
                  + "(LECTURER_ID,QUESTION,SCHEME) "
                  + "VALUES ((Select LECTURER_ID,? from DEMO.LECTURER where LECT_NAME = '" +nameL+ "'), ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement theStatement=theConnection.prepareStatement(str,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    //Set parameters for INSERT statement and execute it
    theStatement.setString(1, nameL);
    theStatement.setString(2, questionL);
    theStatement.setString(3, schemeL);
    theStatement.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet QUES_ID = theStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            QUES_ID.next();
            int autoGeneratedID = QUES_ID.getInt(1);

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.out.println(sqle);
    }

            theConnection.close(); //Close database Connection
    }catch(Exception e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());//Print trapped error.
} finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
} 

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

And this is my html form

```
 "            <form class=\"col-md-9\" name=\"form1\" action=\"InputQuestion\">\n" +

            "            <b><legend>Maklumat Soalan (Esei):</legend></b>\n" +   

            "            <label>Soalan :</label>\n" +
            "            <textarea class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"question\"  placeholder=\"Soalan\" rows=\"6\"></textarea>\n" +

            "            <label>Skema Jawapan :</label>\n" +
            "            <textarea class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"scheme\" placeholder=\"Skema Jawapan\" rows=\"6\"></textarea>\n" +

            "            <br>\n" +

            "            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name_lec\" value= "+ theResult.getString(2) +">\n" +
            "            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Hantar\">\n" +
            "            <input type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" value=\"Penetapan Semula\">\n" +

        "            </form>\n" +
```

Comment: No error but when I submit, there is nothing in that particular database table.

Comment: if you are not getting any thing then print some text in all the section like "database connecting" executing query you may find which section is not working.